# Can this problem be solved using deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, regression, xgboost

I want to predict price of used cars. I have data like this:

[image: Data]

Is this problem suitable for deeplearning or Should I use XGBOOST, RandomForest etc.?

I used one hot approach for nominal features and scaled numeric values between 0-1. Is there anything I can do to improve my data?

I used deeplearning4j on java and predict prices with 10-15% error but I want to predict prices with 1-2% error

Comment: Be careful: ML approaches might give you a 1-2% error margin **on average**, but you can't guarantee that every individual prediction is within a 1-2% error margin. This means that you might find cases where the predicted price is 200% off the real value.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need uncertainty estimates around your predictions, I would recommend just using XGBoost regression and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a case for "deep learning", I think, and I would start with boosting. I have good experiance with catboost (in Python). It can handle factors very well ("catfeatures", encoded as dummies) and it is relatively fast. Also lightgbm might be a good option. Also xgboost is an option.

I think data-wise one hot encoding and scaling is the first thing to do. Things beyond that is a bit try and error. The most important part might be that you tune your hyperparameter well (during boosting).

Catboost (Python): https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-usages-examples.html
LightGBM (Python): https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Python-Intro.html

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I would say start with data cleaning to get a better sight of the problem. Remove all the unnecessary fields, this way you can get a clear picture of which algorithm to use. 
If no of categorical features are higher than non-categorical features in your data, Trees will work better

Answer (score 0):

use a dense layer neural network.   Feed the network as many features of the used car possible as 1 or 0 for each feature that is non quantative.  bin the prices into multiple categories creating a multiple input and multiple output dense layer network

https://www.kaggle.com/austinreese/craigslist-carstrucks-data

use the kaggle dataset to predict price.